# Using SUDS Python WSDL client and Django Sentry, Exception with __sentry__ attribute

Tags: python, django, suds, sentry

When using SUDS in a Django app, alongside Sentry error logging, I hit a problem where SUDS raises an error and Sentry tries to handle it, fails horribly and causes a server 500:

```
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error] Unable to process log entry: plugin domain (__sentry__), invalid
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/client/models.py", line 38, in sentry_exception_handler
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     message_id = get_client().create_from_exception(**extra)
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/client/base.py", line 220, in create_from_exception
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     frames = varmap(shorten, reporter.get_traceback_frames())
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 68, in varmap
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = [varmap(func, f, context) for f in var]
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 66, in varmap
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = dict((k, varmap(func, v, context)) for k, v in var.iteritems())
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 66, in <genexpr>
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = dict((k, varmap(func, v, context)) for k, v in var.iteritems())
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 68, in varmap
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = [varmap(func, f, context) for f in var]
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 68, in varmap
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = [varmap(func, f, context) for f in var]
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 70, in varmap
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     ret = func(var)
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 235, in shorten
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     var = transform(var)
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/helpers.py", line 101, in transform
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     callable(getattr(value, '__sentry__', None)):
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]   File "/opt/envs/xxxx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/plugin.py", line 208, in __getattr__
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error]     raise Exception, 'plugin domain (%s), invalid' % name
[Wed Sep 14 16:06:22 2011] [error] Exception: plugin domain (__sentry__), invalid
```

Seems like Sentry and SUDS don't play well...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like SUDS is actually throwing the incorrect error type in its plugin file, and so Sentry is not able to handle it (Sentry tries to call `__sentry__` on the object that raised the exception, and I guess expects an `AttributeError` to be returned. SUDS just raises an (old-style) Exception...

see: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/browser/trunk/suds/plugin.py#L208

Maybe patch it to raise an AttributeError... but that may not be the best solution... any others?

Comment: Yeah that fixes it! Probably SUDS needs a patch I guess but I can't be bothered to make a fedorahosted account...